# Replace function in SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis, expression, etl, derived-column

There are 3 column in my Sender Master table, First_Name, Middle_Name,Last_Name. Whenever I am loading data from a csv file, Last name gets filled in Middle name.
I am trying to Replace Last_Name with middle using Derived Expression but getting failed every time..

I have tried this code but getting last name in both the fields.
I want to replace Last name with middle and make middle name column blank.

```
LastName == " " ? REPLACE(lastName,"",MiddleName) : LastName
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data as to what is in each column. And also what you want the result to be after it passes through the derived column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using replace function? Just use the following expression:

```
LTRIM(LastName) == "" ? MiddleName : LastName
```

And for MiddleName column, replace it with the following derived column:

```
LTRIM(LastName) == "" ? "" : MiddleName
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is your request... "I want to replace Last name with middle and make middle name column blank."

Make new columns instead of replacing data.

```
drvLastName = MiddleName
drvMiddleName = ""
```

You can now map these new columns to your table.

**NOTE:**

REPLACE is used for switching out chars in a string for example.

```
REPLACE("String,With,Commas",","," ")

will return: "String With Commas"
```